# Why authorization is not works correct in OKTA claims?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, okta

Im trying to make login with okta and my main page display me my claims:

[image]

Despite of that I can't go to pilots page, code is below:

```
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Everyone()
        {
            //that works!!!
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "Pilots")]
        public IActionResult Pilots()
        {
            //that not works
            return View();
        }
```

I have :
This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:5001/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FPilots
HTTP ERROR 404

can someone tell me why it not works? I can add that if I try to add [Authorize(Roles = "Everyone")] it will also not works...